# Is the pullback of a submersion map injective or surjective?

Tags: linear-algebra

A very basic question.

Let $f:M\longrightarrow N$ be a smooth submersion map, we know that its pushforward $f_*:TM\longrightarrow TN$ is surjective. Then what about its pullback $f^*:T^*N\longrightarrow T^*M$? Is it injective or surjective?

Comment: The way you’ve written things, $f_*$ is not surjective unless you assume that $f$ is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is injective Infact if you consider

$w,\theta \in T^*N$ such that $f^*(w)=f^*(\theta)$ then for every $v\in T N$ you have that there exists $a\in T M$ such that $v=f_*(a)$ and so

$w(v)=w(f_*(a))=w\circ f_*(a)=f^*(w)(a)=$

$f^*(\theta)(a)=\theta(f_*(a))=\theta(v) $

Then

$w(v)=\theta(v)$ so $w=\theta$

There is a problem for the surjectivity because if you consider

$w\in T^*M $ you want built $\theta: TN\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f^*(\theta)=w$

The idea could be to define for all $v\in TN$

$\theta(v):=w(a)$ where $a$ is an element of $TM$ such that $f_*(a)=v$

The problem is that there could be two different $a,b\in TM$ such that $f_*(a)=f_*(b)=v$ but in general there is the  possibility that $w(a)\neq w(b)$ so $\theta$ is not well defined.

You can observe that all proofs are not dipend by the contest of the differential geometry, Infact these are general results of linear geometry.